# For can be used for honeymoon?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?

- They went on their honeymoon to Italy.
- They went for their honeymoon to Italy.

Comment: What do Google searches suggest?

Comment: With the preposition *on* the possessive pronoun does not usually occur -- "They went **on honeymoon** to Italy." OTOH, "They went **for their honeymoon** to Italy" is fine.

Comment: @Kris Absolute nonsense. “They went on their honeymoon” is perfectly standard and common. In American English, at least, I'd say it's the most common way of phrasing it. Compare how “they went on their honeymoon to” yields about 3,000 Google hits, while “they went for their honeymoon to” yields only 22 hits.

Comment: Note that most of the hits for "for" involved Indian-sounding names, so I would surmise that it's considered normal to say it that way there.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the sentences to be inverted.

> •They went to Italy on their honeymoon.
>
> •They went to Italy for their honeymoon.

**They went to Italy on their honeymoon** - this means that whilst they were honeymooning, they took a trip to Italy. They may also have taken trips to other places during the same honeymoon. The sentence can be paraphrased, "They went to Italy *whilst* on their honeymoon."

**They went to Italy for their honeymoon** - this means that they went to Italy for the whole period of their honeymoon. Italy was their honeymoon location of choice.

**Answer**

Both are correct - they have different meanings.

**EDIT**

@hd01 - I'll add to my answer in order to address your comment about the first sentence being a quotation from a textbook.

If someone said to me, "They went on their honeymoon to Italy", the precise meaning would depend both on context and intonation. As I have been given neither, I can only go on what is written. Here is a plausible context that I have invented.

*"The couple had a choice. They could cancel their honeymoon to Italy or John could attend the job interview.
They went on their honeymoon to Italy."*

Note that in this context "honeymoon-to-Italy" is inseparable. I'll show this explicitly.

"The couple had a choice. They could cancel their *honeymoon-to-Italy* or John could attend the job interview.
They went on their *honeymoon-to-Italy*."

This means that the example given in the textbook is justifiable but it has yet another meaning which is quite distinct from *"They went to Italy on their honeymoon."*

I may have been hasty in inverting the sentences but my versions are **much** more likely. The textbook version requires contextualisation in order to be idiomatic.

I hope this helps,

Comment: I have seen the first sentence in ' English vocabulary in use, Elementary' book of Cambridge University Press (Unit 2)

Comment: @hd01 - What you have omitted from your question is *context*.  English is a context-dependent language. The same phrase can have different meanings according to what comes before it. Is the text online? Do have a link to the actual page?  In any case I'll add to my answer to cover the implied question in your comment.

Comment: -1 Do not rephrase :) This is not the answer.

Comment: @Kris - fair enough. I originally rephrased to avoid simply saying that the expressions were both wrong (or at least not idiomatic).  As a result of hd01's comment, I realised that the original sentences *could* be justified. However you are quite right: by altering the given data I did not answer the given question - or if I did it was in an indirect fashion.  I'll try to do better next time!  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Note that in American English at least, “They went on their honeymoon to Italy” would be a perfectly common, standard way of expressing that Italy was the destination of their honeymoon; that they honeymooned in Italy. Even “They went to Italy on their honeymoon” would likely be assumed (unless context suggested otherwise) to mean the same thing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It looks as though my answer is more based on my personal opinion than I thought. I won't change it now - I'll leave it for hd01 to judge. Additionally I'll put in a plea that questioners should be urged to give context.  A simple bit of background information or a quote from the surrounding text can make a world of difference in how English is interpreted.

Comment: @charslyfromUK: The sentence is not in a specific text. Before text is: They(got) married in 1988. and the after text is: They were married for 20 years. That is it. only three sentence. The unit is about birth,marriage and death with three brief section about those words.